# How to reverse x-axis without changing image?

Tags: matlab, axis-labels

In MATLAB, I want to reverse my x-axis, but I dont actually want to reverse the image/graph when doing this. I want the image/graph to remain unchanged while I simple reverse the x-axis ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x=0:10;
y=x.^2;

plot(x,y);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',fliplr(x));
```

**EDIT:** To select the amount of decimals, use:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',sprintf('%.2f |',fliplr(x)'));
```

where `2` is the number of decimals that you want

Comment: this worked!...but for some reason now it made all the tick marks go out to like the 6th decimal. How do I get it to just round the values  i.e. it is like this right now : 0.342058, but I just want it to show 0.34

Comment: It will only let me execute the last set() command it sees. So I can get the decimals to what I want, but then I lose the reverse. How can I put it all into one line of code under the set() command?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying the `XTickLabel` property of your `axis` object:

```
x = 1:10;
axishandle = axes;
plot(x)

oldticks = get(axishandle,'XTickLabel');
newticks = fliplr(str2num(oldticks).');
set(axishandle,'XTicklabel',newticks);
```